# Estimate joint density with 2d Gaussian kernel

Tags: python, function, kernel-density, probability-density

I have the following data set where I have to estimate the joint density of 'bwt' and 'age' using kernel density estimation with a 2-dimensional Gaussian kernel and width h=5. I can't use modules such as scipy where there are ready functions to do this and I have to built functions to calculate the density. Here's what I've gotten so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

babies_full = pd.read_csv("https://www2.helsinki.fi/sites/default/files/atoms/files/babies2.txt", sep='\t')

#Getting the columns I need
babies_full1=babies_full[['gestation', 'age']]
x=np.array(babies_full1,'int')

#2d Gaussian kernel 
def k_2dgauss(x):
    return np.exp(-np.sum(x**2, 1)/2) / np.sqrt(2*np.pi)

#Multivariate kernel density
def mv_kernel_density(t, x, h):
    d = x.shape[1]
    return np.mean(k_2dgauss((t - x)/h))/h**d

t = np.linspace(1.0, 5.0, 50)
h=5
print(mv_kernel_density(t, x, h))
```

However, I get a value error 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,) (1173,2)' which  think is because different shape of the matrices. I also don't understand why k_2dgauss(x) for me returns an array of zeros since it should only return one value. In general, I am new to the concept of kernel density estimation I don't really know if I've written the functions right so any hints would help!

Comment: Your first issue is ```(t-x)```. ```t``` has shape (50) and ```x``` has shape (1173,2) so there is no way that python can currently do this first operation.

What exactly is it you want ```(t-x)``` to do here? We can then try and come up with a way to do this. Are you trying to make a 2D histogram / PDF? Or are you trying to do some sort of smoothing with a 2D gaussian kernal?

Comment: @StevenThomas Thank you for your reply! I am trying to estimate the joint density of the two columns 'bwt' and 'age' by using the 2D gaussian kernel to get a smooth density. I would eventually like to get the value of the estimated density at a specific point of age and bwt.

Comment: I'm still unsure exactly what you're intending based off the question you initially asked. For example, what is the array ```t``` you have mentioned? And what is the significance of the ```h=5```? I think you are mixing up a gaussian function with a normal distribution maybe? I will give an answer below to what I think you are after, and how I would do it. If it's not correct then please let me know.

Comment: I was trying to write the mv_kernel_density() based on the d-dimensional kernel density estimate formula 1/(nh^d)*sum^n_{i=1} K*((x-x_i)/h) where x is t in my formula and x_i is x. This was on my textbook but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation#Definition has a similar formula (the same idea?) and now when I look at it, t should have been d-dimensional as well. Sorry if this is confusing, I'm still very new to this subject and a little confused!

Comment: Ok, this is different to what I thought you wanted, and I'm not sure I'm the person to be able to help you with this I'm afraid. That said, I can still look at your code and tell you what isn't working. in the bit of ```k_2dgauss``` you have ```np.sum(x**2, 1)``` but this isn't correct syntax. Let's start with this part. What do you want this to do? What sort of variable should x be here? Is it a single number/float? Or is it going to be an array? If an array, 1D or 2D?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comments on your original post, I think this is what you want to do, but if not then come back to me and we can try again.

```
# info supplied by OP
import numpy as np
import pandas as pdbabies_full = \
pd.read_csv("https://www2.helsinki.fi/sites/default/files/atoms/files/babies2.txt", sep='\t')
#Getting the columns I need
babies_full1=babies_full[['gestation', 'age']]
x=np.array(babies_full1,'int')

# my contributions
from math import floor, ceil
def binMaker(arr, base):
    """function I already use for this sort of thing.
    arr is the arr I want to make bins for
    base is the bin separation, but does require you to import floor and ceil
    otherwise you can make these bins manually yourself"""
    binMin = floor(arr.min() / base) * base
    binMax = ceil(arr.max() / base) * base
    return np.arange(binMin, binMax + base, base)

bins1 = binMaker(x[:,0], 20.) # bins from 140. to 360. spaced 20 apart
bins2 = binMaker(x[:,1], 5.) # bins from 15. to 45. spaced 5. apart

counts = np.zeros((len(bins1)-1, len(bins2)-1)) # empty array for counts to go in
for i in range(0, len(bins1)-1): # loop over the intervals, hence the -1
    boo = (x[:,0] >= bins1[i]) * (x[:,0] < bins1[i+1])
    for j in range(0, len(bins2)-1): # loop over the intervals, hence the -1
        counts[i,j] = np.count_nonzero((x[boo,1] >= bins2[j]) * 
                                        (x[boo,1] < bins2[j+1]))
# if you want your PDF to be a fraction of the total
# rather than the number of counts, do the next line
counts /= x.shape[0]

# plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm

# setting the levels so that each number in counts has its own colour
levels = np.linspace(-0.5, counts.max()+0.5, int(counts.max())+2)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis') # or any colormap you like
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6,5), dpi=150)
pcm = ax.pcolormesh(bins2, bins1, counts, ec='k', lw=1)
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax, label='Counts (%)')
ax.set_xlabel('Age')
ax.set_ylabel('Gestation')
ax.set_xticks(bins2)
ax.set_yticks(bins1)
plt.title('Manually making a 2D (joint) PDF')
```

[image]

If this is what you wanted, then there is an easier way with `np.histgoram2d`, although I think you specified it had to be using your own methods, and not built in functions. I've included it anyway for completeness' sake.

```
pdf = np.histogram2d(x[:,0], x[:,1], bins=(bins1,bins2))[0]
pdf /= x.shape[0] # again for normalising and making a percentage

levels = np.linspace(-0.5, pdf.max()+0.5, int(pdf.max())+2)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis') # or any colormap you like
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6,5), dpi=150)
pcm = ax.pcolormesh(bins2, bins1, pdf, ec='k', lw=1)
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax, label='Counts (%)')
ax.set_xlabel('Age')
ax.set_ylabel('Gestation')
ax.set_xticks(bins2)
ax.set_yticks(bins1)
plt.title('using np.histogram2d to make a 2D (joint) PDF')
```

[image]

**Final note** - in this example, the only place where `counts` doesn't equal `pdf` is for the bin between 40 <= age < 45 and 280 <= gestation 300, which I think is due to how, in my manual case, I've used `<=` and `<`, and I'm a little unsure how `np.histogram2d` handles values outside the bin ranges, or on the bin edges etc. We can see the element of `x` that is responsible

```
>>> print(x[1011])
[280   45]
```